# jsonschema-master to validate json request not responding as expected

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, jsonschema

I am trying to use jsonschema-master to validate a json request entered via a POST request using express. See the code and sample below.

It picks up if the attribute labels are missing or spelt wrong, such as “model”, “areas”, “id” but isn’t picking up if the values of those attributes meet the specifications. For example the “model” attribute is defined as an enumerated type either “premium” or “basic”, but I seem to be able to put any old string in there and it plows on regardless, also the coordinates are defined as type number, but again it ignores this and the error then gets passed the validator and causes problems further on. Not sure what I'm missing.

node.js code:

```
var Validator = require('jsonschema-master').Validator;
var v = new Validator();
var bodySchema = {
      "model": { 
        "enum": [ "premium","basic" ] 
      },
      "areas": {
        "type":"array",
        "items": {
          "id": {"type": "string"},
          "geometry": {
            "type": { "type":"string"},
            "coordinates": {
               "type":"array",
               "items": {
                 "type":"array",
                 "items": [
                   {"type":"number"},
                   {"type":"number"},
                   {"type":"number"}
                 ]
               }
            },
            "required" : ["type","coordinates"]
          },
          "required" : ["id","geometry"]
        }
      },
      "required" : ["model","areas"]
};
var valResult = v.validate(doc.request, bodySchema);
if (valResult.errors.length) {
  // Validation failed.
  // All processing will now stop.
  console.log('Request invalid: '+ doc._id +" - "+valResult.errors);
}
```

SAMPLE CORRECT JSON request (in doc.request)

```
{
  "model": "premium",
  "areas": [
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              453600.0,
              181100.0,
              0
            ],
            [
              453600.0,
              181200.0,
              0
            ],
            [
              453700.0,
              181200.0,
              0
            ],
            [
              453700.0,
              181100.0,
              0
            ],
            [
              453600.0,
              181100.0,
              0
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, but I worked it out in the end. Here is the corrected syntax for the schema:

```
var bodySchema = {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties": {
        "model": { 
            "enum": [ "premium","basic" ] 
        },
        "areas": {
            "type":"array",
            "items": {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties": {
                    "id": {"type": "string"},
                    "geometry": {
                        "type" : "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "type": { "type":"string"},
                            "coordinates": {
                                "type":"array",
                                "items": {
                                    "type":"array",
                                    "items": {
                                        "type":"array",
                                        "items": [
                                            {"type":"number"},
                                            {"type":"number"},
                                            {"type":"number"}
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "required" : ["type","coordinates"]
                    }
                },
                "required" : ["id","geometry"]
            }
        }
    },
    "required" : ["model","areas"]
};
```